# How to remove circle from Google Maps V3?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polyline

I have drawn circle using

```
    circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    map: map,
    radius: r,    // 1 miles in metres = 1609.3 m
        strokeWeight:1,
        strokeOpacity:0.5,
        fillOpacity:0.2,
        fillColor: '#AA0000'
    });
    circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
```

How to remove circle from the map ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
circle.setMap(null);
```

will remove the circle

Comment: Hi @Bader, I'm using pin drop on google map, when I click on map, 1 marker will show with circle radius. If I click another place on map, marker will be removed and showed on new position where I click, but circle radius can not remove. How can we remove all circle radius except circle has marker on it?