# Draw a "Corridor" with Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dictionary, coordinates

I'm trying to replicate a map from a GPS Provider, i can access to every shape in the map with an API, but i'm having issues with the "Corridor" shape.

A corridor is like a Polygon but when you draw it you define a Width (in meters) and "click" on some points for some "precision":

[image: Corridor config]

As you can see, every white box is a "click" and the blue line is the "corridor".

My question is how can i draw it? because I tried with a Polyline but it doesn't work as expected, when I zoom out it looks weird:

[image: corridor at this moment]

(What i have now)

[image]

(how it should look)

I guess I must draw a Polygon for it, but i don't know how to calculate the coordinates of the edges because the API only returns the points of the "precision" and the width but no the corner coordinates.

Some ideas ?

Comment: 1. Draw a polyline.
2. Calculate the Buffer(polygon) of that polyline using turf. The buffer is your corridor. http://turfjs.org/docs/#buffer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
          strokeColor: '#737CA1',
          strokeOpacity: 0.5,
          strokeWeight: 3,
          map: map,
});
```

The weight can be adjusted for your preferred width.

Also try to remove the circle, as suggested in this answer: [removing-a-google-maps-circle-shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260029/how-to-remove-circle-from-google-maps-v3)

```
circle.setMap(null);
```

Comment: I tried Polylines, but the circle that you see is a polyline with zoom out, it looks like a circle :/ that's why polylines doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to compute two coordinates offset with half with separation in each direction from center and give them perpendicular bearing from centerline bearing with sphericalutil library from google maps, then you add all those point to a polygon in the correct order and you get a polygon with a fixed with respect a centerline.